# Can a hosted node support calling only whitelisted smart-contracts?

Tags: nodes, smartcontracts, aeternity-blockchain

I tried to calling only whitelisted smart-contracts with a hosted node support.

I used the >dry-run API. 
But seems that not work. 
I will be grateful for any recommendation on what to solve this problem.

p.s. Smart-contracts are written on aeternity's Sophia language.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean by whitelisted smart contracts. I think on two ways, in one hand you can have your own whitelisting contracts where you say which one are the contracts address list you will support.

On the other hand you could just know which caller address is the right one for those contracts.

There is a good example for whitelisting oracles on superhero implementation here:

https://github.com/aeternity/tipping-oracle-service/blob/master/contracts/OracleService.aes

Even though it's not a contract lists the concept behind is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at https://api-docs.aeternity.io/#/debug/DryRunTxs there doesn't seem to be native support for this in the Node API. Therefore, I guess you'd have to request such a feature or implement support for it.